# the image of a self map on a simply connected topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:X \to X$ be a map where $X$ is a topological space. If $X$ is simply connected, does this mean that $f(X)$ is also simply connected?

I've tried to prove this using the following characterization but to no avail:
a top. space $Y$ is simply connected if and only if for any map $g:S^{k-1} \to Y$ we have an extension $g':D^k \to Y$ where $k = 1, 2$.

It is clear that $f(X)$ is path connected, so we only need to confirm the criterion above for $k=2$, but I have no idea how to do this.

As to counterexamples, there are many counterexamples for $f:X \to Y$ but not if $f$ is a self map, maybe I've missed some obvious counterexamples?

Comment: No condition on $f$? You can say nothing about the image.

Comment: @geetha290krm no condition on $f$

Comment: How about a function with just two values?

Comment: @geetha290krm It has to be continuous, sorry I implicitly assumed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its false. Take for example the Complex plane and the exponential map.

Comment: Ah right... I can't believe I missed this counterexample, thanks! Are you willing to maybe give some hint to the context of the question? (I added some text)

Comment: OP does not even mention continuity, so there are much better counter-examples.

Comment: @geetha290krm ah sorry I implicitly assumed continuity since we’re working with topological spaces